# Does the File Separator Matter for Java File Paths?

Tags: java, file, upload, path, separator

I'm pentesting a Java web application that uploads a file to the server.  It uses an old library - com.jspsmart.upload.smartupload - which as far as I know should work.  The saveAs method requires a path where the file should be saved.  I've tried uploading files and cannot get it to work.  I feel like the issue might be with the file path.  If the install directory is something like C:\my_app the path would be C:\my_app\uploads/filename.txt.  Does this matter?  Or might something else be causing it not to upload?  The upload code is surrounded by a try/catch and doesn't return an exception, so I'm not sure why it wouldn't work.

Some documentation I found on the library: http://demo.easyhis.com/jspsmartupload/help/doc/com/jspsmart/upload/File.html

Sample code:

```
private static string FS = System.getProperty("file.separator");

try {

    myFile = myUpload.getFiles().getFile(0);
    importFolder = Globals.getInstallDir() + FS + "uploads";
    myFile.saveAs( importFolder + "/" + request.getParameter("import_file_name"), SmartUpload.SAVE_PHYSICAL);

} catch (Exception e) {
    // outputs error
}
```

Comment: Ouch, naming a class `File` when there is `java.io.File`...

Answer (score 0):

Java can indifferently use `/` or `\` as a file separator under Windows, but it is one or the other -- don't do both!

Anyway, use `Path`, you will then be sure that you get a correct path to work with:

```
Paths.get(Globals.getInstallDir()).resolve(FS).resolve("uploads")
    .resolve("import_file_name").toString();
```

Note that `FS` should NOT be absolute here (ie, no beginning `/` or `\`).

Answer (score 0):

Use [File.separator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#separator). It returns the system's default path to a specific file separator.

```
private static string FS = File.separator;
```